# Unable to perform Selective File Restore from a SME Server 7.5.1 backup

Tags: restore

Customer has an old SME Server 7.5.1 server (based on CentOS 4.8). A staff member accidentally deleted her entire personal data drive, and there exists a weekly backup in the server's Backup Information Bay.

When I choose Selective File Restore from Workstation, it gives me the error "Unable to mount workstation shared folder error -1 opening credential file /etc/dar/CIFScredentials".

I had assumed that CIFS was installed, however:

```
[root@server dar]# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   cgroup
nodev   devpts
nodev   mqueue
        ext4
nodev   nfs
nodev   nfs4
nodev   delayfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   sysfs
nodev   proc
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   binfmt_misc
nodev   fusectl
nodev   fuse
```

The only response to my google search to fix this was to install CIFS, however that seems counter-intuitive, since the server is using another filesystem. I attempted to check through the system logs to find more information, however the SME Server view logs did not have any information in the current backup log regarding my attempted restore, nor was there any corresponding restore log.

When I did attempt to install CIFS, I got this:

```
[root@server dar]# sudo yum install cifs-utils
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Loading "smeserver" plugin
Loading "protect-packages" plugin
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: smeaddons
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: smeaddons
```

The file I wish to restore is a 2.1TB .tgz file, so I think I should be able to unpack it back to its original ibay, but I'm unsure how to proceed. One issue about this version of SME was that backups did not work with files 2TB, and this one is 2.1TB.

I inherited this server which is weeks away from being replaced by a Windows server, and I only have limited experience with CentOS. Can anyone help me get this restore working? Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 7zip to expand the files on the external USB, then simply copied them back to the users folder.